# Accessing protected member function in derived class — Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ogdf

I am trying to use OGDF C++ library for a project and want to use a protected member function of a class of this library. I can't access protected members directly outside class or derived class, so to use protected method of Balloon Layout class I created a class `A` which inherits from `BallonLayout`. From `A`, a protected function of the super class is called in a public function `abc()` of class `A`; so that I can use `abc()` outside the class and indirectly protected function of class `BallonLayout`.

Here's the code, please tell me where there is a problem in it.

```
#include <ogdf/basic/Graph.h>
#include <ogdf/basic/graph_generators.h>
#include <ogdf/misclayout/BalloonLayout.h>

using namespace ogdf;

class OGDF_EXPORT A : public BalloonLayout{
        public:
            void abc(const Graph &G){
            selectRoot(G); //Calling super class protected method.               
            }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 5, m = 7;
    Graph G;
    ogdf::planarBiconnectedGraph(G, n, m);

    A* a = new A;
    a->abc(G);
    cout << "Done!!";
return 0;

}
```

It compiles without any error but at run time it gives “Segmentation fault (core dumped)”. This error comes when we try to access something (object/variable) which is not in memory. But I do not understand what mistake have I done.

In place of `A* a = new A; a->abc(G);`, I tried the following too but I am getting the same error.

```
A* a; 
a->abc(G);
```

and

```
A *a = new A;
a->abc(G);
delete a;
```

and

```
A a;
a.abc(G);
```

Foe each one of the attempts above, I get a segmentation fault. This error is coming after calling `a.abc(G)` when this method calls the superclass's method.

Comment: `A* a;` does not point to anything , you should change that do `A* a = new A;` or `A a; a.abc(G);`

Answer (score 4):

```
A* a;
a->abc(G);
```

That creates a pointer without initialising it; then attempts to dereference that invalid pointer to call a function. The result is a segmentation fault, or other undefined behaviour.

You almost certainly want to create an object:

```
A a;
a.abc(G);
```

Comment: I have tried also but getting same error :(
Also used delete a; but not working.

Comment: @Shaifali: Don't use `delete` unless you created the object with `new`. If you've made the change I suggested and it's still crashing, then the error is in some code you haven't posted.

Comment: please look at the edited question; I tried all cases but its giving segmentation error at run time for all.

Comment: @Shaifali: If you're still getting a segfault, then it's time to get out the debugger and find where it's happening. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, once you make this change.

Comment: After calling a.abc(G); Geting this fault while calling "selectRoot(G);" that is function of super class. Please can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: @Shaifali: Sorry, I can't help; that's a problem with either the library, or your usage of it, and I don't know anything about the library.

Comment: this is link for its documentation of that method if you can figure out my mistake http://www.ogdf.net/doc-ogdf/classogdf_1_1_balloon_layout.html#aff8cd83738568fb26b3ff21aaa466a4e